# zero frequency in Naive Bayes

Tags: r, nlp, naivebayes, divide-by-zero

Can we handle a class which is not a part of training data but present in test data and our predictor classify that data as ‘Other’ label class?

```
pred <- predict(classifier, data$test)
```

Comment: @Andy: thanks for editing. In general, if you see chatty material like "Please help me out", just remove it, rather than replacing it with new chatty material. "I am new" can probably go as well, as it can be inferred, but it does have a bit of value, I guess. I've removed it in this case.

Comment: hi @halfer, sounds good. Thanks for the advice.